# How to make a GRAV plugin to display something on the browser?

Tags: grav

I am new to Grav cms and wanted to learn about the plugins. I tried making one but I wanted to make that plugin display something on the screen when I hit an particular route. Is there any online source to learn about this or can anyone help with this?

Comment: Are you aware of https://learn.getgrav.org? See chapter 4

Comment: *"make that plugin display something"*, what for example? *"when I hit an particular route"*, is it the route of a page or a non-existing route?

Comment: I am just trying to print something on the browser like "hello world". Yes for non existing route. Also would like to know about route with page.